# libgdx project generation gradle error

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to generate a libgdx project but I'm getting the following error related to gradle.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\libgdx\gametest\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\libgdx\gametest\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\libgdx\gametest\build.gradle': 5: unexpected token: } @ line 5, column 5.
         }
         ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. Open the grade file. Change line 5 from

```
maven { https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ }
```

to:

```
maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
```